# docker - build fails when COPYing file to root

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm getting a docker build error when I try to add a shell script to the root directory (/entrypoint.sh)

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Output:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.072 kB
Step 1 : FROM ubuntu:trusty
 ---> 1e0c3dd64ccd
Step 2 : COPY ./entrypoint.sh /
stat /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/5570570a77deddea426b95bd0f706beff4b5195a2fba4a8f70dcac4671bca225/entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory
```

The file is present at the root of the build context, and when I change / to a subdirectory such as /opt/, it works. Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: `COPY entrypoint.sh /`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your Dockerfile - I've just built an image using it with no problems. You see this error if you try to `COPY` from a fully-qualified source path, because the source needs to be in the build context, but relative paths are fine. Check your source file name is correct?

Comment: @bjhaid Nope, still doesn't work

Comment: @EltonStoneman Yep, the file's named `entrypoint.sh` in the same directory as the Dockerfile. This is also a toy example I created because it was happening on another build with different filenames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out restarting the daemon solves the issue. See https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/25925.